# Non-nullable instance field 'searchResultsFuture' must be initialized. How do i resolve this without using late

Tags: flutter

```
<kbd>
class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  Future<QuerySnapshot> searchResultsFuture; //The problem is here


  handleSearch(String query) {
    Future<QuerySnapshot> user =
        usersRef.where("displayName", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query).get();
    //.getDocuments()
    setState(() {
      searchResultsFuture = user;
    });
  }

</kbd>
```

Have used late Future searchResultsFuture;
and the highlighted error gone but the code didn't work

Comment: check this: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score 0):

use ? operator after QuerySnapshot or after this ( > )

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> searchResultsFuture;
```

to

```
Future<QuerySnapshot>? searchResultsFuture;
```

to make it nullable